# Centering text in console C#

Tags: c#, console, centering

Currently I am using this method to centre my text in the console.

```
string x = "Whatever I want to print goes here";
Console.SetCursorPosition((Console.WindowWidth - InvalidNo.Length) / 2, Console.CursorTop);
Console.WriteLine(x);
```

However I now need to centre something that looks like this:

```
players[PlayerNo].Name + " has stolen a piece of cheese from " + players[choice - 1].Name
```

and something like this

```
"Player {0}", playernum + 1
```

Is there any way to do that with my method, or would I have to use something different?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see a method there, just a code snippet which does not even compile. So how the method you are talking about looks like from outside?

Comment: @Bart: Please improve the question to provide as much info as you can. If you are new here, please go through site tour first; http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with your method, you just have to create the string first so that you know how long it is:

```
string x = players[PlayerNo].Name + " has stolen a piece of cheese from " + players[choice - 1].Name;
```

Then you can just use the rest of your code.

For the second example it used the overload of the `WriteLine` method that takes a format string, so you would use the `String.Format` method to create the string:

```
string x = String.Format("Player {0}", playernum + 1);
```